# Want to make figure go below panels

Tags: java, swing, layout

I have to make a drawing tool and here's my problem

[image]

[Screenshot of another case the issue happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cv8Tv.png)

So when the figure go into another panel, so the panel with the buttons and the panel with the parameters, i want the figure to go below these panels

```
JPanel panel_contenu = new JPanel();
panel_contenu.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
setContentPane(panel_contenu);
panel_contenu.setLayout(null);

JPanel panel_dessin = new JPanel();
panel_dessin.setBounds(0, 139, 1257, 831);
panel_contenu.add(panel_dessin);
panel_dessin.setOpaque(true);

JPanel panel_parametre = new JPanel();
panel_parametre.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 1, true));
panel_parametre.setBounds(1264, 0, 247, 977);
panel_contenu.add(panel_parametre);
panel_parametre.setLayout(null);

JPanel panel_boutons = new JPanel();
panel_boutons.setBounds(0, 0, 1264, 101);
panel_contenu.add(panel_boutons);
panel_boutons.setLayout(null);

if (cbo_listeobj.getSelectedItem() instanceof Triangle) {
    Triangle t = new Triangle();

    t = (Triangle) cbo_listeobj.getSelectedItem();

    t.deplacer(val_vect_x, val_vect_y);

    repaint();
} // this is when i move a figure

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponents(g);
    Point2D p1 = new Point2D(val_p1_x, val_p1_y);// Commun à toutes les figures

    // TRIANGLE
    if (Btriangle2) {
        Point2D p2 = new Point2D(val_p2_x, val_p2_y);
        Point2D p3 = new Point2D(val_p3_x, val_p3_y);

        Triangle t = new Triangle(p1, p2, p3);
        colltri.add(t);

        listeobj.add(t, cbo_listeobj);

        Btriangle2 = false;
    }
    colltri.afficher(g); //this is when it paint the contentPane

    btnOk.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        edt_vect_x.setEditable(true);
        edt_vect_y.setEditable(true);
        btnDepl.setEnabled(true);

        if (Btriangle) {
            Btriangle2 = true;
            Btriangle = false;

            val_p1_x = Integer.parseInt(edt_p1_x.getText());
            val_p1_y = Integer.parseInt(edt_p1_y.getText());

            val_p2_x = Integer.parseInt(edt_p2_x.getText());
            val_p2_y = Integer.parseInt(edt_p2_y.getText());

            val_p3_x = Integer.parseInt(edt_p3_x.getText());
            val_p3_y = Integer.parseInt(edt_p3_y.getText());

            repaint();
        } // the ok Button display the figures
```

So my main problem is when you display or move the figure, the figure go through the other panels and don't go below the other panels, you see the figures go through the panels, like in the screenshot.

I want the figure to go below the other panels when they are displayed and when you move the figure with the parameters. I have 4 panels 
`panel_contenu` which is the contentPane and include the other panels 
`panel_dessin`,`panel_parametre` and `panel_boutons`.

Comment: Don't post screenshot of code. Copy/pasting text is easier, faster and more persistent. And it doesn't force people to re-type all the code.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], so we can better understand where is your mistake. This would also be helpful for us to provide a solution, that is suitable for your case.

Comment: You don't use a layout and components' bounds overlap

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use a null layout (Swing was designed to be used with layout managers)
2. Don't use setBounds() (it is the job of the layout maanger to set the size/location of components.
3. Don't override paint()
4. Don't invoke paintComponents() directly (Swing will do this).

Custom painting is done by overriding paintComponent() on a JPanel. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

Then you add different panels to the frame:

1. one for the toolbar
2. one for the custom painting

So the basic logic would be:

```
JPanel toolBarPanel = new CustomToolBarPanel();
JPanel paintingPanel = new CustomPaintingPanel();
frame.add(toolBarPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START)
frame.add(paintingPanel, BurderLayout.CENTER);
```

The tutorial link from above also contains a section on `How to Use BorderLayout`.